# How to AUTO-EMPTY fields in a form AFTER submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, joomla, form-submit

I'm using this ( http://www.j-download.com/demo/demo-j-dcontact.html ) form on my website. It works great but the only issue is that AFTER successfull submission ALL the fields are STILL FILLED.
Can somebody please help me with this, I would like so the fields are auto-emptied after successfull submission..

Thanks.

Comment: Use the reset() function; something like this after the form submits: `$('#myForm').reset();`. You could also loop through all the given form elements with `$('#myForm').find(':input').each();`.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I've done it now by adding 

    `document.getElementById("form").reset();`

to the template .php file of the form AFTER form submission

Answer (score 7, accepted):

can be acheived with jquery or raw javascript after the post and [it is explained here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-clear-form/)

This script is from that site (in case the link dies)

```
function clear_form_elements(ele) {
    $(ele).find(':input').each(function() {
        switch(this.type) {
            case 'password':
            case 'select-multiple':
            case 'select-one':
            case 'text':
            case 'textarea':
                $(this).val('');
                break;
            case 'checkbox':
            case 'radio':
                this.checked = false;
        }
    });
}
```

you could also `reset()` the form

Comment: Thanks everybody. I've done it now by adding 

    `document.getElementById("form").reset();`

to the template .php file of the form AFTER form submission